# Can I put black paint on a cow mangler?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I am currently debating buying black paint from somebody in tf2. However, the main reason I want it is so i can put it on either my cow mangler or my eureka effect. Am I able to put "A Distinctive Lack of Hue" paint on any of these two paints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you cannot. It is only possible to use paint on Cosmetic Items.**

At one point long ago, you would have been able, however, to paint a Cow Mangler. Though this only worked with team-coloured paint cans.

This is no longer possible, and these painted weapons are incredibly rare to find.

Comment: wait, then how r there australium weapons

Comment: Now that's a completely different story. Australium weapons are not actually painted, they're just made out of gold (or Australium, rather). The only way you can obtain those is by completing a Two Cities tour on Mann vs Machine, where you get a rare chance to earn one.

Comment: @Texenox Australiums/Golden Pans can be earned by completing any Advanced or Expert MvM tour.  This change was put into effect in the Love & War Update.

Comment: @AndrewEckert Okay, so my mistake, you can earn Australium weapons through any Advanced or Expert tour. Now, if you found any answers here useful, feel free to mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot put paint on a weapon.

> The Paint Can is a tool that allows players to change the coloring of most **Cosmetic items**.

-[TF2 wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Paint_Can), emphasis mine